# What type of trees are these two?

Tags: identification, trees

I have two trees along with a tomato plant that have sprung up in the garden, I suspect birds as I cant see anything else similar. I would like to know what they are to see if I should keep them and replant somewhere or dispose of them. I am located on the Gold Coast Australia if that helps.

[image: First Tree, I tied to remove this tree as it was too close the the fence and I damaged the roots to much, but I would still like to know what it was.]

[image: First tree, from the side]

[image: Second Tree]

[image: Second Tree close up]

Answer (score 1):

First two pics appear to be *Murraya koenigii* or Curry Tree. Produces white flowers with red then black fruits. Keys to identity are leaf shape and the fact of a compound leaf with alternate leaflets. Most compound leaves have opposite leaflets.

The third and fourth pics I think are a species of Hibiscus, although not sure of species or variety. Leaf shape, plus again alternately arranged on the twigs, plus the spotty bark.

Both could be considered valuable and interesting specimens, worthy of transplant during dormant season to a location where they have more space to grow.

Answer (score 0):

Trees that close to fences and retaining walls are rarely a good idea. They'll eventually start pushing the barrier over or lifting it up. I'd remove them.

Comment: That is the plan, but I want to know if I should dispose of them or replant them.